# Why can't I convert this varchar to numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linqpad

I have a table with values pasted in, but they initially start as varchar. I need to convert them to numeric, so I did

```
convert(decimal(10,3), cw.col7)
```

But this is returning `Error 8114: Error converting data type varchar to numeric`. The reason I made this question is because it does not give this error for a similar data set. Are there sometimes strange anomalies when using `convert()` or `decimal()`? Or should I maybe convert to float first?

**The data:**

```
col7

490.440 
2 
934 
28,108.000 
33,226.000 
17,347.000 
1,561.000 
57 
0 
421.350 
64 
1,100.000 
0 
0 
3,584 
202.432 
0 
3,280 
672.109 
1,150 
0 
104 
411.032 
18,016 
40 
510,648 
443,934.000 
18,705 
322,254 
301 
9,217 
18,075 
16,100 
395 
706,269 
418,313 
7,170 
40,450 
2,423 
1,300 
2,311 
94,000.000 
17,463 
0 
228 
884 
557 
153 
13 
0 
0 
212.878 
45,000.000 
152 
24,400 
3,675 
11,750 
987 
23,725 
268,071 
4,520.835 
286,000 
112,912.480 
9,000 
1,316 
1,020 
215,244 
123,967 
6,911 
1,088.750 
138,644 
16,924 
7,848 
33,017 
464,463 
618 
72,391 
9,367 
507,635.950 
588,087 
92,890 
17,266 
0 
1,414,547 
89,080 
664 
101,635 
1,552,992 
175 
356 
7,000 
0 
0 
445 
507,381 
24,016 
469,983 
0 
0 
147,737 
3,521 
88,210 
18,433.000 
21,775 
3,607 
34,774 
7,642 
42,680 
1,255 
10,880 
350,409.800 
19,394.520 
2,476,257.400 
778.480 
1,670.440 
9,710 
24,931.600 
3,381.800 
2,900 
18,000 
4,121 
3,750 
62,200 
952 
29.935 
17.795 
11.940 
902 
36,303 
1,240 
1,020 
617 
817 
620 
92,648 
70,925 
82,924 
19,162.200 
1,213.720 
2,871 
3,180 
91,600 
645 
607 
155,100 
6 
840 
1,395 
112 
6,721 
3,850 
40 
4,032 
5,912 
1,040 
872 
56 
1,856 
179
```

Comment: Remove comma and then convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Try_Convert(money,...)` will handle the comma, while decimal(10, 3) will return null

**Example**

```
Select col7
      ,AsMoney   = Try_Convert(money,col7)
      ,AsDecimal = Try_Convert(decimal(10, 3),col7)
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention - this column is not currency. I might need to show 3+ decimal places, depending.

Comment: @DarthVoid My answer would round the values to 4 decimals.  If you need more, then scaisEdge's answer would be best.  Just change the decimal(10,3) to the appropriate precision.

Comment: I went with this one. Thanks.

Comment: @DarthVoid Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Try using cast   and remove comma

```
 SELECT CAST(repalce(cw.col7,',','') AS DECIMAL(10,3))
 from your_table
```

and as suggested  by  Jhon Cappelleti  you need  more that 3 decimal so you should use

```
 SELECT CAST(repalce(cw.col7,',','') AS DECIMAL(12,4))
 from your_table
```

Comment: I also verified that `isnumeric(cw.col7)=1` for all of my data

Comment: then  show the contenct of cw.col7 ...   could is not numeric or is not compatible with 10,3

Comment: OP needs more than 4 decimals (contrary to the question)  Sooo...  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti   many thanks  ... answer  update  with your suggestion ... upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

```
select cw.col7
from cw
where try_convert(decimal(10, 3), cw.col7) is null;
```

This will show you the values that do not convert successfully.  (If `cw.col7` could be `NULL` then add `and cw.col7 is not null` to make the output more meaningful.)